# Symmetric Coprime Pairs

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've been thinking about the distribution of the coprimes of n, and in particular, about one particular symmetry that they have. Here's a problem that I have formulated for myself:

Given natural numbers $n > 0$ and $m$ prove that there exists $0 < k < ub(n)$ such that $(n, m-k) = 1$ and $(n, m+k) = 1$.

The theorem states that for all $n$ and $m$, there are a pair of coprimes of $n$ symmetric about $m$ in a range determined by the function $ub(n)$.

I've convinced myself that such a pair of coprimes exists, but I am unsure how to approach the bound.

My conjecture is that $ub(n) = c$ * [the largest prime divisor of n]. But I do not know how to confirm or refute that claim. Does anyone have any insight on how to approach the bound on $k$, as stated in my problem above?

*This is a problem I am working on for fun. It is not a homework assignment.

Comment: n=210, m=43; would your bound hold?

Comment: It does not. k=24, which yields m-k = 19 and m+k = 67 are the closest pair of coprimes of the 4th primordial number. My bound on k would have been 22. I've updated my best guess in the problem. Can you tell me how you came up with 210 and 43? That would be quite useful.

Comment: Brute force search, that's how.

Comment: So I'm not concerned with the specifics of my initial guess. It was just a place to start. Do you have any advice on how to go about characterizing the bound?

Comment: No, I don't see anything better than the obvious ub(n)=n.

Comment: Well the coprimes of n are periodic, with period equal to the product of the prime divisors of n, which is a bit better. But I conjecture that the bound is actually much tighter.